# jQuery Quiz Project: Append Image After a Text Field to Denote Right or Wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

https://jsfiddle.net/boriskay/thsmdqrt/

Here's a simple text field quiz. What I need is for a Checkmark or an X(wrong) icon to appear directly to the right after each text field.

The text fields have a CSS Position: absolute.

HTML:

```
<div id="map">
    <img src="http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/productImages/1000/eb/ebd83d8b-6e6f-4526-8dd9-e063f0ef66bd_1000.jpg">


<form>  
        <input id="q1" type="text" />
        <input id="q2" type="text" />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Click When Done" />
</form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/quiz.js"></script>
```

JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY:

```
var answers = {
    "q1": ["Camisas", "camisas", "CAMISAS"],
    "q2": ["Zapatos", "zapatos", "ZAPATOS"]
    };



function markAnswers() {
    $("input[type='text']").each(function() {
        console.log($.inArray(this.value, answers[this.id]));

    if($.inArray(this.value, answers[this.id]) === -1) {
        $(this).parent().append("<img class='result_pic' src='https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/geomicons/32/672366-x-128.png' />");

    } else {
        $(this).parent().append("<img class='result_pic' src='http://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/74/74414.png' />");
        $("form").append("Great job!");
        }
    })
}

$("form").on("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    markAnswers();
    $("form").append("Great job!");
});
```

CSS:

```
#q1, 
#q2 {
    position: absolute;
    display:inline-block;
    z-index:100;
    height: 20px;
}

#q1 {   
    margin-top: -450px;
    margin-left: 350px; 
}

#q2 {   
    margin-top: -160px;
    margin-left: 350px;
}

.result_pic {
    position: relative;
    z-index:100;
    display:inline;
}

#submit {
    height: 35px;
    font-size: 17px;
    background-color: skyblue;
}

ol {
    list-style: none;
}
```

Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First :: Wrap both of input into separate div and apply `position:absolute;` on these div instead of the inputs.

Second :: define `width` and `height`for images. and apply `display:flex;` to containing div. and also apply `align-items:center;` to make both input and the image to be vertically centered.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thsmdqrt/2/) and below is working snippet.

```js
var answers = {
    "q1": ["Camisas", "camisas", "CAMISAS"],
    "q2": ["Zapatos", "zapatos", "ZAPATOS"]
};

function markAnswers() {
 $("input[type='text']").each(function() {
  console.log($.inArray(this.value, answers[this.id]));
 
 if($.inArray(this.value, answers[this.id]) === -1) {
  $(this).parent().append("<img class='result_pic' src='https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/geomicons/32/672366-x-128.png' />");
  
 } else {
  $(this).parent().append("<img class='result_pic' src='http://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/74/74414.png' />");
  $("form").append("Great job!");
  }
 })
}

$("form").on("submit", function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 markAnswers();
 $("form").append("Great job!");
});
```

```css
#q1C, 
#q2C{
 position: absolute;
 display:flex;
 z-index:100;
  align-items:center;
}
#q1,#q2{
  height: 20px;
  float:left;
}

#q1C{ 
 margin-top: -450px;
 margin-left: 350px; 
}

#q2C{ 
 margin-top: -160px;
 margin-left: 350px;
}

.result_pic {
 position: relative;
  z-index:100;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  margin-left:5px;
}

#submit {
 height: 35px;
 font-size: 17px;
 background-color: skyblue;
}

ol {
 list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map">
 <img src="http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/productImages/1000/eb/ebd83d8b-6e6f-4526-8dd9-e063f0ef66bd_1000.jpg">
  <form> 
    <div id="q1C"><input id="q1" type="text" /></div>
    <div id="q2C"><input id="q2" type="text" /></div>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Click When Done" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you. I'm new here, I upvoted your comment, is there anything else I should do?

Comment: @Boris K.    ..you have to accept the answer, click on the checkmark on the left of my answer. It is right below the up and down arrows with 0 in between.

Comment: Once you click on it, I get points for my effort and you also get points for successful question. The checkmark will turn green then. Like this image: http://imgur.com/gallery/iBwN4